# I can't run features files withe Cypress 10

Tags: cypress

I was trying to run Cucumber files (.feature) with last version of Cypress 10.0.3, but I couldn't run it. After I finished the configuration, I could see the featur file in Cypress interface but if I try to run it, Cypress give me an error back (see screenshot).

My `webpack` file:

```
    module.exports = {
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".cy.ts", ".cy.js"]
        },
        node: {fs: "empty", child_process: "empty", readline: "empty"},
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.cy.ts$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/],
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "ts-loader"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.cy.feature$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/loader"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.cy.features$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/featuresLoader"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

My `Cypress.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  fileServerFolder: ".",
  fixturesFolder: "./cypress/fixtures",
  video: true,
  videosFolder: "./cypress/videos",
  videoUploadOnPasses: false,
  screenshotsFolder: "./cypress/screenshots",
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  responseTimeout: 60000,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 60000,
  reporter: "cypress-multi-reporters",
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,

  reporterOptions: {
    configFile: "cypress/reporter-config.json",
  },

  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.cy.feature",
    // testFiles:
  },
})
```

Screenshot:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/93645203/172401189-52032d06-7ffa-45a6-8be7-fc7df2ecdf4e.png

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do, but to interpret gherkin feature files in cypress you need cypress-cucumber-preprocessor. Here is a link how to install and configure with cypress https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/readme.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed with Cypress V 10.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Please install `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@l1.0.0` for a fix for this issue.

Comment: I have it already!

Comment: It's a version that fixes that particular error, verified by multiple users on the issue log. What are you doing differently?